# Heap corruption when adding a node to a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I'm new to C and at a loss.  I've been beating my head against a wall for hours.

I create two `struct`s to hold my linked list nodes.  The first, `struct movie` obviously holds movies.  The second `struct actor` is to add actor nodes to the movie nodes.

```
struct movie {
    struct movie* next;
    struct actor* actors;
    char name[100];
    int rating;
    genre type;
} *list = NULL;


// contains actor information
struct actor {
    struct actor* next;
    char name[100];
};
```

The trouble comes when I try to add a `actor` to a `movie`.

```
int add_actor(char* movie_name, char* actor_name)
{
    struct movie *tmp = list, *tmpList = NULL;
    struct actor *tmpActor = NULL, *current = NULL;

    //check if movie name exists in list
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(tmp->name, movie_name) == 0) {
            tmpList = tmp;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }                                                                       //make sure newActor->next is pointing to the correct place
    if (tmpList == NULL) { return 0; } //if movie in not in list, return 0

    //The problem occurs most often at this line, with the exception below.
    //Exception thrown at 0x77433500 (ntdll.dll) in hw7.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x006F4E42
    struct actor *newActor = (struct actor*)malloc(sizeof(struct actor));//create new actor node

    if (tmpList->actors == NULL){ //if the movie has no actors in list
        tmpList->actors = newActor;
        strcpy(newActor->name, actor_name);
        newActor->next = NULL;
        return 1;
    }
    else { //check if actor name already exists in list
        while (tmpActor != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(tmpActor->name, actor_name) == 0) {
                return -1; //if actor already exists return -1
            }
            tmpActor = tmpActor->next;
        }

        tmpActor = tmp->actors;

        //insert at beginning of list
        if (strcmp(actor_name, tmpActor->name) >= 0) {
            newActor->next = tmpActor;
            tmpActor = newActor;
            return 1;
        }
        //insert actor in arbitrary position
        while (tmpActor != NULL && strcmp(actor_name, tmpActor->name)<0) {
            current = tmpActor;
            tmpActor = tmpActor->next;
        }
        newActor->next = current->next;
        strcpy(newActor->name, actor_name);
        current->next = newActor;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

At best I have been able to add two actors to two different movies.  The problem always comes on the third entry.

Here is the Exception thrown
[image]

UPDATE:

After meticulously picking through my code, I discovered a glaring error. The program would crash when passed anything bigger than a few characters.  When I declare the `movie_name` and `actor_name` pointer variable that are passed to the `add_actor` function I didn't allocate enough room for larger names.

```
char* movie_name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
char* actor_name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

After changing to:

```
char* movie_name = (char*)malloc(5000*sizeof(char*));
char* actor_name = (char*)malloc(5000*sizeof(char*));
```

I'm able to add movies and actors without crashing.

Comment: As it stands, this is a LOT of code to go through. Could you possibly [edit] and collapse it down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Thank you!

Comment: Edit complete, thanks

Comment: Suggest reading [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) (again). Creating this MCVE will lead to discovering the bug yourself in 80% of all cases, and in the remainder, help others to help :)

Comment: While I don't know much about heap corruption personally, [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1081496&seqNum=2) also seems to have some good information.

Comment: If a `malloc()` blows up like that, it probably means that you've already corrupted the heap by writing beyond the end of some allocated memory, modifying the control information that `malloc()` relies on.  So, the chances are that the problem won't be solved by looking at this code — you need to look elsewhere.  If [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) is available on your platform, use it.

Comment: Your 'search for the movie' loop should probably be in its own separate function.  The loop should break when the name is found, unless you really want to find the last movie of the same name in the list (but why would you be allowing duplicate movies in the list?).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the line specified (the cast isn't necessary, but doesn't hurt), and I see no code that could possibly corrupt the heap except that strcpy(), which is fine as long as actor names are 99 characters or fewer. Whatever is corrupting your heap, it isn't here. I suspect something else is corrupting it, and that malloc() is just the next thing it does, and so that's where it notices.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for that, I did ask for criticism and that was the most constructive I've ever received. Investigating this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two errors.
It's unlikely that either of these is the source of the crash, though, since neither is executed in your test case. (Unless you're adding two actors to *each* movie – the question is hard to interpret on that point).
The ultimate cause might be in the function that adds movies, or somewhere else.
When the heap has become corrupted, all you can say for sure is that it happened at some point between the start of the program and the crash.

But I'll mention these errors anyway...

One:

When you get to this point:

```
tmpActor = tmp->actors;
```

`tmp` is guaranteed to be `NULL` from your first loop.
You probably meant

```
tmpActor = tmpList->actors;
```

Two:

When you get here:

```
    //insert at beginning of list
    if (strcmp(actor_name, tmpActor->name) >= 0) {
        newActor->next = tmpActor;
        tmpActor = newActor;
        return 1;
    }
```

you assign your new actor to `tmpActor`, which is a local variable.

I think you should replace

```
tmpActor = newActor;
```

with

```
tmpList->actors = newActor;
```

And three: don't cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: The `tmpActor = tmp->actors;` should definitely be `tmpActor = tmpList->actors;` and with just that change, I was able to create three movies and add three actors to each of two movies and have [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) only complain (quite reasonably) about leaked memory.  Obviously, I had to write an `add_movie()` function and I managed to get that sufficiently right that it didn't cause problems.  I didn't write code to print the data, so there could be other issues I didn't find.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct movie MOVIE;
typedef struct actor ACTOR;



typedef enum {
    Action,
    Documentary,
    Animation /*etc ...*/
}genre;
struct movie{ 
    MOVIE* next; 
    ACTOR* actors; 
    char name[100]; 
    int rating;    
    genre type; 
} ;
// contains actor information

struct actor { 
    ACTOR* next; 
    char name[100]; 
};

MOVIE *list = NULL;



/*_______________________________________________________
*/
MOVIE *List_FindMovie(const char *movie_name){
    MOVIE *tmp = list; 

    while (tmp != NULL) { 
        if (_stricmp(tmp->name, movie_name) == 0) {
            return tmp; 
        }        
        tmp = tmp->next; 
    }
    return NULL;
}

/*_______________________________________________________
*/
ACTOR *Movie_FindActor(MOVIE *movie,const char*actor_name){
    ACTOR  *tmpActor=movie->actors;
    while(tmpActor){
        if(_stricmp(tmpActor->name,actor_name)==0)
            return tmpActor;
        tmpActor=tmpActor->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
 /*_______________________________________________________
*/
int List_ActorInfo(const char *actor_name){
    MOVIE *tmp = list; 
    int nmovies=0;
    printf("Actor '%s' participations:\n",actor_name);
    while (tmp != NULL) { 
        if(Movie_FindActor(tmp,actor_name)){
            nmovies++;
            printf("\t- %s\n",tmp->name);
        }
        tmp = tmp->next; 
    }

    if(nmovies)
        printf("\t  Total: %d movies\n\n",nmovies);
    else
        printf("\t  None\n\n");
    return nmovies;
}   
/*_______________________________________________________
*/
ACTOR *NewActor(const char*actor_name){
    ACTOR *NewActor=calloc(1,sizeof(ACTOR));
    strcpy(NewActor->name,actor_name);
    return NewActor;
}
/*_______________________________________________________
*/
ACTOR *Movie_AddActor(MOVIE *movie,ACTOR *NewActor){
    if(!movie->actors){
        movie->actors=NewActor;
    }else{
        ACTOR *prevActor=NULL,*current=movie->actors;
        while(_stricmp(current->name,NewActor->name)<0){

            prevActor=current;
            current=current->next;
            if(!current)break;
        }
           NewActor->next=current;
            if(prevActor)
                prevActor->next=NewActor;
            else
                movie->actors=NewActor;

    }
    return NewActor;
}


/*_______________________________________________________
*/
MOVIE * List_AddMovie(const char *movie_name,genre type){
    MOVIE *movie,*tmpMovie;
    if(movie=List_FindMovie(movie_name)) return 0;

    movie=calloc(1,sizeof(MOVIE));
    strcpy(movie->name,movie_name);
    movie->type=type;
    if(!list)
        list=movie;
    else{
        tmpMovie=list;
        while(tmpMovie->next)
            tmpMovie=tmpMovie->next;
        tmpMovie->next=movie;
    }
    return movie;
}
/*_______________________________________________________
*/
void Movie_PrintActors(MOVIE *movie){
    ACTOR *actor=movie->actors;
    printf("Actors in Movie '%s':\n",movie->name);
    while(actor){
        printf("\t%s\n",actor->name);
        actor=actor->next;
    }
    printf("\n");

    return;
}
/*_______________________________________________________
*/

int main(){
    MOVIE *mv;


    List_AddMovie("Dogs",0);
    mv=List_AddMovie("Dragons",0);


    if(!mv){
        printf("failed to add movie\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    Movie_AddActor(mv,NewActor("Z"));
    Movie_AddActor(mv,NewActor("C"));
    Movie_AddActor(mv,NewActor("A"));
    Movie_AddActor(mv,NewActor("Cat8"));
    Movie_PrintActors(mv);

    mv=List_FindMovie("Dogs");
    Movie_AddActor(mv,NewActor("Dog1"));
    Movie_AddActor(mv,NewActor("Dog3"));
    Movie_AddActor(mv,NewActor("Dog6"));
    Movie_AddActor(mv,NewActor("Cat8"));

    Movie_PrintActors(mv);

    List_ActorInfo("Bruce Lee");
    List_ActorInfo("Cat8");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: i just reformat your code to make it more clear and maintenable, no bugs right now (think to free memory alocated)

Comment: Looks great.  I saved your code to study as it is much cleaner!  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: While  ACTOR actor; is not used but is miss taped it should be ACTOR  *actor;